# File doesn't exist even it is there at Physical Location

Tags: asp.net, iis

Our  Hosting server recently shifted from Microsoft server 2003 to 2008 and Accordingly we we Configured **IIS 7.0**
In  one of our module we are Checking if file exist from a perticular physical path for example

```
 if (File.Exists(@"C:\logo.jpg"))
        {
            // some logic
        }
```

Actually when I go to that **Physical path**  for logo.jpg file do exist but from code perspective
It doesn’t exist What I am doing wrong here,It all working in my older server with **IIS 6**

**Note:** I am matching from Physical path because i have plenty of such *.jpg file (more than 10000)

Please Suggest if have any clue

Many Thanks

Comment: make sure you have permission to access to the file.

Comment: it's odd that your web app is reading from root of C drive. you should create sub folders and set permissions to the web app user. by default, if your web site name is ABC, a local user ABC will be created too. useful reading http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981949

Comment: If asking questions, it is wise to provide actual data, otherwise people will write answers based on wrong assumptions. My first though would also be that the IIS user is not allowed to read from C:\.

Comment: Yes it is the permission issue,it works after appropriate permission

Answer (score 2):

Move your logo to some place where the IIS user can read, such as the project directory or a subdirectory of that directory, and update the code to read the logo from there instead.